# Finding the equation of a plane that passes through the line of intersection of 2 planes and forms a 45 degree angle with another plane.

Tags: plane-geometry

How to find the equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of the planes $x+5y+z=0$ and $x-z+4=0$, and that forms a 45 degree angle with the plane $x-4y-8z+12=0$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sort of question comes up all the time here. You ought to be able to find an answer by searching for them.

Comment: Try exploring some of the related questions on the right.